# Entity Framework - use LocalDb and SQL CE simultaneously

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-connection, connection-string, localdb

I'd like to provide an option to use LocalDb or embedded database in my application. Installed EF 6, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact and Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact packages.

Here is what I have in App.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\databasesdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

If I try to create DbContext instance passing a connection string to the LocalDb database, than get an exception (Keyword not supported: "initial catalog").

So, how to get ability to connect to one or another database depending on run-time settings? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Code Based configuration, and have some external way of setting the desired database (config / registry setting) - and a change will require an app restart: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680699(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Indeed, that helped and works fine. Thank you, Erik, it was easy.